# C++ Comparison Operator Overloading const vs non-const Behaviour

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, c++20

I recently noticed some operator overloading behaviour that I could not figure out myself. The following two classes only differ in the `const` on the member comparison operator overloads of `ClassA`. In `ClassB` they are not const. Generally I know that one would always prefer the `const` one, but still I am interested in why we see the behaviour I will describe below.

```
#include <string>

class ClassA {
public:
    explicit ClassA(double t) : _t(t) {}

    std::string operator<=(int const& other) const {
        return "A(<=)";
    }

    std::string operator==(int const& other) const {
        return "A(==)";
    }

    friend std::string operator<=(int const& other, ClassA const& expr) {
        return "A'(<=)";
    }

    friend std::string operator==(int const& other, ClassA const& expr) {
        return "A'(==)";
    }

private:
    double _t;
};

class ClassB {
public:
    explicit ClassB(double t) : _t(t) {}

    std::string operator<=(int const& other) {
        return "B(<=)";
    }

    std::string operator==(int const& other) {
        return "B(==)";
    }

    friend std::string operator<=(int const& other, ClassB const& expr) {
        return "B'(<=)";
    }

    friend std::string operator==(int const& other, ClassB const& expr) {
        return "B'(==)";
    }

private:
    double _t;
};
```

Now I want to use these classes and comparison functions in `const` and non-const scenarios.

```
int
main(int argc,
     char* argv[]) {
    ClassA a1{0};
    1==a1; //OK
    1<=a1; //OK
    ClassA const a2{0};
    1==a2; //OK
    1<=a2; //OK
    ClassB b1{0};
    1==b1; //NOT OK
    1<=b1; //OK
    ClassB const b2{0};
    1==b2; //OK
    1<=b2; //OK

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine but the one line that I marked `NOT OK`. This throws a compiler error.

```
error C2446: '==': no conversion from 'ClassB' to 'int'
```

My question splits up into three parts, but I would expect that there is one good reason that answers all of them. So I hope it is still fine to post this into one single SO question.

> Why is the equality operator `==` not compiling, when the inequality `<=` is? Why does it matter for the friend functions whether the member functions are `const` or not? And why does making the `ClassB` object `const` fix it?

### **Updates:**

- In the comments @Eljay pointed out that the problem is probably created by the a new C++20 feature that automatically generates comparison operators with inverted arguments. This apparently makes member `std::string operator==(int const& other)` (after re-arrangement) a better match for the `1==b1`. After some digging I found the rule saying these should be generated in the rules for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Call_to_an_overloaded_operator).

> 4. rewritten candidates:
>
> - For the four relational operator expressions x<y, x<=y, x>y, and x>=y, all member, non-member, and built-in operator<=>'s found are
>   added to the set.
> - For the four relational operator expressions x<y, x<=y, x>y, and x>=y as well as the three-way comparison expression x<=>y, a
>   synthesized candidate with the order of the two parameters reversed is
>   added for each member, non-member, and built-in operator<=>'s found.
> - For x!=y, all member, non-member, and built-in operator=='s found are added to the set.
> - For equality operator expressions x==y and x!=y, a synthesized candidate with the order of the two parameters reversed is added for
>   each member, non-member, and built-in operator=='s found.
>
> In all cases, rewritten candidates are not considered in the context
> of the rewritten expression. For all other operators, the rewritten
> candidate set is empty.

- @463035818_is_not_a_number pointed out some interesting finding about different compilers that can and can not compile the code in different versions. Specifically for `clang` and `gcc` with the flag `-std=c++2a` the newest versions `x86-64 clang 12.0.0` and `x86-64 gcc 11.1` do not compile, while older versions `x86-64 clang 9.0.1` and `x86-64 gcc 9.4` do. For VisualStudio we see a similar pattern with the flag `/std:c++latest`. Here the newest version `x64 msvc v19.28 (VS16.9)` does not compile, where the direct predecessor `x64 msvc v19.28` does. These test where made with the Compiler explorer [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/jxzYY1hxb).
- It is particularly interesting to note that the compiler errors of `clang` and `gcc` suggest that the problem is that `std::string operator==(int const& other)` is not returning a `bool`.

**clang**

```
error: return type 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') of selected 'operator==' function for rewritten '==' comparison is not 'bool'
    1==b1; //NOT OK
```

**gcc**

```
error: return type of 'std::string ClassB::operator==(const int&)' is not 'bool'
    1==b1; //NOT OK
```

While these are all very interesting insights the original question still remains open.

Comment: It should be compiling afaik... also  C++ now supports sharship operator and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons

Comment: The `operator==` is not returning a `bool`.  That makes the C++20 spaceship synthesizer grumpy.

Comment: Yeah, try to add prints inside the body of the operators, while maintaining proper semantics for everything.

Comment: My C++20 intellisense gives me a slightly more informative answer: `function "ClassB::operator==" ... selected for operator rewrite does not return type bool`. It looks like the non-`const` `B` is prompting comparison synthesis which fails because `operator==` doesn't have the appropriate semantics. And `<=` is presumably working because the absence of `<=>` means it doesn't even try to synthesize `<=` and successfully uses the free function `operator<=`.

Comment: I think what's happening is ClassB member `bool operator==(int const&)` (after the spaceship synthesizer and re-arranger) is a better match for the `1==b1; //NOT OK` than the friend `operator==`, because the `friend` has a `const` ClassB reference and `b1` is not const.

Comment: By the way, well written question.  The example may seem non-minimal at first, but after digging into it a little it really is nicely minimal and still provide sufficient context.

Comment: Based on your comments I tried to disable the spaceship feature by using an older C++ standard (I chose 11) and indeed everything compiles perfectly. Thus it seems like this feature is actually able to break code.

Comment: Also it seems to be specific to VisualStudio. I tested `g++` as @rawrex suggested and everything perfectly compiled even with the C++20 flag `c++2a`.

Comment: @SimonT so it is almost surely implementation dependent then.

Comment: gcc (`-std=c++20`) complains with "error: return type of 'std::string ClassB::operator==(const int&)' is not 'bool'" https://godbolt.org/z/146TY8Yq5, though gcc compiles it without complains without the c++20 flag.

Comment: clang as well fine with -std=c++17 but fails with c++20

Comment: Why pass an `int` via const reference instead of by value? Doing this won't provide any benefits.

Comment: @fabian you are right generally it is a better to not use `const&` for `int`. But for the sake of this question it does not matter.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number what's funny it compiled for me. I guess that's really depends on version and patch. and technically, where is restriction in standard that requires that?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I guess its a sideeffect of the threeway comparison introduced in C++20 that this does not compile. Perhaps not all such sideeffects were taken into account in older gcc versions. I find it a little sad that "return type of `operator==` is not `bool`" seems to be an error now

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number "Standard is software and as any software it can have bugs"

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie https://godbolt.org/z/cM7K1a6Mn. I think I'll add the `language-lawyer`

Comment: @SimonT how about rephrasing your question a little? Consider this: https://godbolt.org/z/cM7K1a6Mn. Your code compiled with gcc and clang with older versions but both reject the code in the latest version. It almost looks like it was a bug/ missing feature and was "fixed" recently. On the other hand, "return type of `operator==` is not `bool`" as an error looks so strange that I don't want to believe it. Perhaps also add the `language-lawyer`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number 11.1 rejects it with very interesting different error. for -non-const instance it considers to switch arguments around and use `ClassB::operator==(int const& other)`, so `1==b1` appears to be equal to `b1==1`,

Comment: but it isn't, `b1==1` usage doesn't produce error

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I updated the question with the insights we got so far. I also added VS to the your compiler comparison. Thanks for pointing out that website to me by the way. I've been looking for something like that for quite a while now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a concrete answer. But still, let's look into [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

There are **no restrictions on return types** for overloaded operators (since return type does not participate in overload resolution), but there are *canonical implementations*:

> ...the language puts no other constraints
> on what the overloaded operators do, or on the return type, but in general, overloaded
> operators are expected to behave as similar as possible to the
> built-in operators

And then:

> ..the return types are **limited by the expressions in which the
> operator is expected to be used**.
>
> *For example, assignment operators
> return by reference to make it possible to write a = b = c = d,
> because the built-in operators allow that.*

We dig [further](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison):

> ...where built-in operators return bool, most user-defined overloads also
> return bool so that the user-defined operators can be used in the same
> manner as the built-ins. However, in a user-defined operator overload,
> any type can be used as return type (including void).

And even [further](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) *(three-way comparison)*:

> If both operands have arithmetic types, or if one operand has unscoped
> enumeration type and the other has integral type, the usual arithmetic
> conversions are applied to the operands.

So, I would assert that it **depends on an implementation**. On my machine it compiles (g++) and runs:

```
std::cout << (1==b1) << std::endl; // Prints B'(==)
```

### Tiny re-update

[@463035818_is_not_a_number](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/463035818-is-not-a-number): *"The issue was seen in VS. Newer versions of gcc reject such usage as well, same with clang. It rather looks like it was a bug / missing feature and got fixed in more recent versions."*

Here's the [compiler explorer snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/cM7K1a6Mn) with the issue.

Comment: note that it is not really unique to VS, newer versions of gcc reject it as well, same with clang, it rather looks like it was a bug / missing feature and got fixed in more recent versions: https://godbolt.org/z/cM7K1a6Mn